# Widgets not showing on custom theme

Tags: php, theme-development, widgets

I'm implementing some widget area inside my custom theme. I've noticed that the added widgets are not display where I want, It will appear a blank area, also if I create a custom sidebar template for that. Is possible to check if there are widgets active for the theme and how? How I can fix the problem I'm facing?Here is the code I'm using:

functions.php

```
  function contact_widget()
  {
    register_sidebar(
      array(
        'name'          => __('Contact'),
        'id'            => 'contact-info',
        'description'   => __('Contact info'),
        'before_widget' => '<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 contact-widget>',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
        'before_title'  => '<h1>',
        'after_title'   => '</h1>',
      )
    );
  }
  add_action( 'widgets_init', 'contact_widget' );

  function social_widget()
  {
    register_sidebar(
      array(
        'name'          => __('Social'),
        'id'            => 'social-links',
        'description'   => __('Link social'),
        'before_widget' => '<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 text-center>',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
        'before_title'  => '<h1>',
        'after_title'   => '</h1>',
      )
    );
  }
  add_action( 'widgets_init', 'social_widget' );
```

Inside the customizer it will appear only the first widget I've registered but not the second. In the part of the theme where I want to display them will not appear nothing instead. Yhis is the relative code.

```
<?php if( function_exists('register_sidebar') ): ?>
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid services-action">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
<?php if( is_active_sidebar('contact-info') ): ?>
<?php  get_sidebar('contact-info'); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if( is_active_sidebar('social-links') ): ?>
<?php  get_sidebar('social-links'); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I want that this part is showed only if the widgets are active.

The two templates for the sidebar will give a deprecation error if I don't create also the `sidebar.php` file. They only contain for now this line of code:

````
// sidebar-social.php
<?php dynamic_sidebar('social-info'); ?>
// sidebar-contact.php
<?php dynamic_sidebar('contact-info'); ?>
// sidebar.php
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
```
Since the needed div classes are declared inside the registration of the sidebars I've not implemented nothing as html markup inside the templates files. If is possibile I will prefere to implement the div columns inside the sidebar template files instead using the `before_widget` and `after_widget`.
Any help will be appreciated.
````

Answer (score 1):

Try to combine both sidebars/arrays into one function.

```
function my_widgets() {
    register_sidebar(
       array(
       'id' => 'contact-info',
       // add the rest here
       ),
    register_sidebar(
       array(
       'id' => 'social-links',
       // add the rest here
       ))
    );
}
add_action('widgets_init', 'my_widgets');
```

Then you call the deisred sidebar

```
<?php if(is_active_sidebar('contact-info')) : ?>
   <?php dynamic_sidebar('contact-info'); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I discovered that in the widget dashboard of wp the second sidebar area remain collapsed. I think this is because I'm using adblock plus. Now I need to implement a custom widget to output what I want without any wordpress additional div or css class!